# SQLite select field if text inside contains a specific text entered by user

Tags: android, sqlite

My project requires that the user could search for a product by its name
so I have to select all records which contain a specific word (which the user has entered).
I was trying "select Name from Products where Name Like '%" + keyword + "%'"
but it didn't work.
Any solution ?

```
 public Cursor fetchallproducts(String word){
 SQLiteDatabase EcommerceDB;
 EcommerceDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = EcommerceDB.rawQuery("select Name from Products where Name 
 Like '%" + word + "%'" , null);
 If (cursor!=null)
 {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
 }
 EcommerceDB.close();
 return cursor;}
```

Comment: Define "didn't work" what are you getting as result?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm your like string is wrong. it should be `'%keyword%'`

Comment: didn't work as it displays all the records in the database even if it doesn't contain the keyword

Comment: Keyword is a String variable as it's input from user so i have to combine it with the select statement, is there another way i can combine them together ?

Comment: Provide your current code and how you implemented it?

Comment: @Ibrahim the code added in the question

Comment: I still don't know where your issue came from, But It's better to debug on your code, and follow some tutorials to be sure that you have implemented it as well, also you may interested in android [room library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html). It will be helpful in your case.